# how do i stop this print(val.text) from printing the same table 8 times

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am scraping tables from a Matchday dropdown. when the print(val.text) is executed it prints each table 8 times just like the number of rows instead of just once it then moves to the next Matchday and prints the table 8 times.i just want it be printed once. can someone help me find where the problem is. 
i would also like to append the tables scraped to an excel file any assistance would be a appreciated

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.betika.com/mobile/#/virtuals/results')

#Selecting the Season dropdown box
Seasons = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-of-type(1) > .virtuals__results__header__select'))

#Selecting the Matchday dropdown box
Matchdays = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-of-type(2) > .virtuals__results__header__select'))

import time
#selecting all the options the Seasons dropdowns.
Season = len(Seasons.options)
for items in reversed(range(Season)):
    Seasons.select_by_index(items)
    time.sleep(2)
    #selecting all the options the Matchdays dropdowns.
    Matchday = len(Matchdays.options)
    for items in range(Matchday):
            Matchdays.select_by_index(items)
            time.sleep(2)
            rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr')) #count number of rows in the table
            columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td')) #count number of columns in the table
           # print(rows)
           # print(columns)
            for r in range(3,rows+1):
                for c in range(1,columns+1):
                    value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table["+str(r)+"]/tbody/tr["+str(c)+"]')
                for val in value:
                    print(val.text)```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line is your problem.
`value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table["+str(r)+"]/tbody/tr["+str(c)+"]')`

`.format()` is what I would sugest to use. See below. I commented out the problematic line and added my updated line.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.betika.com/mobile/#/virtuals/results')

#Selecting the Season dropdown box
Seasons = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-of-type(1) > .virtuals__results__header__select'))

#Selecting the Matchday dropdown box
Matchdays = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-of-type(2) > .virtuals__results__header__select'))

import time
#selecting all the options the Seasons dropdowns.
Season = len(Seasons.options)
for items in reversed(range(Season)):
    Seasons.select_by_index(items)
    time.sleep(2)
    #selecting all the options the Matchdays dropdowns.
    Matchday = len(Matchdays.options)
    for items in range(Matchday):
            Matchdays.select_by_index(items)
            time.sleep(2)
            rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr')) #count number of rows in the table
            columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td')) #count number of columns in the table
           # print(rows)
           # print(columns)
            for r in range(3,rows+1):
                for c in range(1,columns+1):
                    #value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table["+str(r)+"]/tbody/tr["+str(c)+"]')
                    value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/main/div/div[2]/table['{}']/tbody/tr['{}']".format(r, c))
                for val in value:
                    print(val.text)
```